# How can I avoid Time Machine starts to back up files right after the Mac is restarted?

Tags: snow-leopard, time-machine

Sometimes I have to restart my Mac Mini because an application blocks it.
When I restart it, Time Machine starts to back up files right after 10 seconds I restarted the Mac, and it makes it slowly (I have 4 applications/tools that are opened at login).

Is there a way to avoid Time Machine starts to back up files, if not after X minutes I restarted the Mac (X could be a value between 10-30 minutes)?

Comment: I have already changed the settings using the command line, and now Time Machine is backing up files every 2 hours, instead of every hour as it does by default.

Comment: Which application blocks the Mac as this should be very unusual

Comment: I think it is an utility that replaces some text when I enter it. The point is another one, though; what I described could happen also when I shut down the Mac, and I switch it on right when Time Machine should back up the files. What I want to do is to avoid it does it when the Mac just restarted. The scenario I described is simply that I sometimes reset the Mac while I am doing something urgent and I would like to restart working on it without Time Machine makes the Mac slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found two TimeMachine schedulers softwares: [TimeMachineEditor](http://timesoftware.free.fr/timemachineeditor) and [TimeMachineScheduler](http://www.klieme.com/TimeMachineScheduler.html).

Both are useful to set the backup interval of Time Machine but none of them enable user to define a time limit (after mac startup) before which Time Machine can't be launched.

However, TimeMachineScheduler has an interesting option to skip backup during a user defined time slot. That may be a decent workaround if you're able to define the time slot -during which you may be "doing something urgent"- that requires Time Machine to be off.

Comment: TimeMachineEditor is able to set a different backup interval for different weekdays. I think I will use that; at least I can avoid Time Machine keeps trying to backup data when I am trying to work. Thank you, @kraymer.